# One action after another on the same selector (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to figure this out. I got a selector, with 2 actions :

1) If I click I want to the 1st action to be ran.
2) If the 1st have been clicked, the second click on the object should run the 2nd action.
3) If the 2nd have been click, go back to step 1).

I'm new into Jquery. Is it clear enough ?

```js
  // 1st action
  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $(".dropleft").css("bottom","0vh");
    $(this).css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
  });
  // 2nd action
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $(".dropleft").css("bottom","");
    $(this).css("transform","");
  });
```

Comment: Down-voting is not a nice way of saying welcome to a new user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an IIFE returning a function that will maintain a toggle to the click handler:

```
// 1st action
$('.menu').click((function(toggleValue){
  return function(e){
      if(toggleValue){//first action
        $(".dropleft").css("bottom","0vh");
        $(this).css("transform","rotate(90deg)");      
      }else{//second action
        $(".dropleft").css("bottom","");
        $(this).css("transform","");      
      }
      toggleValue = !toggleValue;//toggle
  }
})(true)/** IIFE */);
```

As for Karl's comment; you could set a user defined attribute on the element if you have multiple .menu elements:

```
// 1st action
$('.menu').click(function(e){
  toggleValue=e.target.getAttribute("data-toggle");
  if(toggleValue!=="toggle"){//first action
    $(".dropleft").css("bottom","0vh");
    $(this).css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
    e.target.setAttribute("data-toggle","toggle");
  }else{//second action
    $(".dropleft").css("bottom","");
    $(this).css("transform","");      
    e.target.setAttribute("data-toggle","next");
  }
  toggleValue = !toggleValue;//toggle
});
```

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Good point, no it won't each .menu needs it's own. You could do `$('.menu').each` to add a listener to each `.menu` updated answer

Comment: Still, I like the IIFE way. The `.each` would bother me, but for a single element, that's a nice way to do it. By the way, you should use `.data` instead of setting an invalid HTML attribute! It would allow you to have a true boolean as well! Just a little tip.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks for the tip, changed the answer to use `data-...` attribute names i thought the spec was any attribute with `something-` was a custom attribute but seems to be anything `data-*` is (for html 5)

Answer (score 1):

Use a single event handler, with a flag stored using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```js
$('.menu')
  .click(function() {
    var $menu = $(this);
    var active = $menu.data('active');
    var $dropleft = $menu.siblings(".dropleft");

    if (active) {
      $dropleft.css("color", "");
      $menu.css("transform", "");
    } else {
      $dropleft.css("color", "red");
      $menu.css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
    }

    $menu.data('active', !active);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="menu">Menu1</button>

  <div class="dropleft">dropLeft1</div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="menu">Menu2</button>

  <div class="dropleft">dropLeft2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using CSS classes and jQuery's `toggleClass` function. Less complex and more maintainable.

CSS:

```
.bottom { bottom: "0vh" }
.rotate { transform: rotate(90deg) }
```

JS:

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
   $(".dropleft").toggleClass("bottom");
   $(this).toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check on some css property

```js
 $('.menu').click(function(){
    const transform = $(this).css("transform");
    if (transform) {
      $(".dropleft").css("bottom","");
      $(this).css("transform","");
    } else {
       $(".dropleft").css("bottom","0vh");
      $(this).css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting 2 functions to execute when you click in menu class.

You should just create one function and control what should execute.

Here is an example:

```js
var control = false;

$('.menu').click(function() {
  if (control = !control) {
    $(".dropleft").css("bottom", "0");
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
  } else {
   $(".dropleft").css("bottom", "");
    $(this).css("transform", "");
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.dropleft {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolue;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  menu
</div>
```